# Alluvial plot vs. Sankey diagram

Tags: data-visualization, terminology, sankey-diagram

Is there any difference between an Alluvial plot and a Sankey diagram? Are these two names for the same thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure there's any consensus on this.

Wikipedia says that an [alluvial diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alluvial_diagram) is a type of [Sankey diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram) "that uses the same kind of representation to depict how items re-group"

[RAWGraphs](https://rawgraphs.io/learning/how-to-make-an-alluvial-diagram/) likewise says:

> Alluvial diagrams are a specific kind of Sankey diagrams: they use the same logic to show how the same set of items regroups according to different dimensions.

[Azavea](https://www.azavea.com/blog/2017/08/09/six-sankey-diagram-tool/) says:

> A Sankey diagram visualizes the proportional flow between variables (or nodes) within a network. The term “alluvial diagram” is generally used interchangeably. However, some argue that an alluvial diagram visualizes the changes in the network over time as opposed to across different variables.

[Datasmith](http://www.datasmith.org/2020/05/02/alluvial-plots-vs-sankey-diagrams/) says they "are profoundly different types of diagram":

> Alluvial plot:
>
> - Shows how a population of facts is allocated across categorical dimensions.
> - Left/right position has no particular significance; dimensions could be in any order.
> - ‘Nodes’ are lined up in columns.
> - Is useful for showing how features of a population are related — for example, answering questions like ‘how many people have features A and B, compared to how many have B but not A?’
>
> Sankey diagram:
>
> - Shows how quantities flow from one state to another.
> - Left/right position shows movement or change.
> - ‘Nodes’ could be anywhere, and must be laid out by an algorithm.
> - Is useful for showing flows or processes where the amount, size, or population of something needs to be tracked — for example, answering questions like ‘out of the energy in system A, how much came from systems B and C and where will most of it go?’

This seems opposite of the Azavea definition?

The Data Visualisation Catalogue Blog [tries to distinguish between them](https://datavizcatalogue.com/blog/sankey-diagrams-parallel-sets-alluvial-diagrams-whats-the-difference/):

> Like with a Flow Chart, a Sankey Diagram can include cycles, which is
> something that distinguishes them from Parallel Sets and Alluvial
> Diagrams.

> Also, the flow paths in a Sankey Diagram can combine or split apart at any stage of the system’s process. Whereas on Parallel Sets and Alluvial Diagrams, you tend to get a group of flow paths only going from one side to the other.

> Parallel Sets and Alluvial Diagrams aren’t too different from one another.  However, the main difference between these two chart types is that Parallel Sets display a part-to-the-whole relationship, while Alluvial Diagrams only visualise quantities between dimensions.

> Parallel Sets will have line-sets that are all uniform in length, while Alluvial Diagrams will have a lot more variation.